# SSAS Calculating "active" or "under warranty" totals between start and end dates

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube

I'm very new to SSAS and data warehouse concepts (but know SQL pretty well), so bear with me.

I'm ultimately trying to figure out a failure rate for parts based on `CLAIMS / PARTS` that are under warranty per month & year buckets.

I've created the warehouse and can calculate the number of claims per bucket no problem. The calculation I'm having trouble with is figuring out the number of parts that are under warranty based on warranty start and end dates.

My fact table has the following columns:

```
[unit_details_id],[unit_id],[part_id],[claim_id] ,[warr_start_date_id],[warr_end_date_id] ,[manuf_date_id],[claim_date_id]
```

To get the claim counts, I created a measure for all non-null `claim_id` values. I now need to create a measure for all parts that are `in warranty` during the claim date buckets I'm using (month & year).

So, for instance, in July 2014, part X might have 10 claims.

- I need to find how many part X's have a `warr_start_date <= 7/2014` and `warr_end_date >= 7/2014`.
- I then need to divide total claims by total `in warranty` for `7/2014` to get the percentage.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would "pre-handle" this requirement in the sql.  Have your measure group pull its data from a view or add a calculated column in the SSAS DataSourceView that includes something like "IsInWarranty" as a 1 or 0, and sum them in the cube.  I assume you will be processing your cube daily, so the value will change as the current date passes the end_warranty date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I'm reading your response correctly, you're suggesting that the "IsInWarranty" column reflect the current date. This won't work, as I need to look at claims in the past (say 7/2010) and look at all of the parts that WERE in warranty for that same month & year, not whether or not the part is currently in warranty.

Comment: If you only care about whether a part was in warranty at the time the claim was made, then why not make it a property of the claim?   Have an "IsInWarranty" column in the claim table, and set it when the claim is created?

Comment: I also need to know the warranty status for all parts that DON'T have claims.  I need PART CLAIMS / TOTAL PARTS IN WARRANTY

Comment: I see.   For total parts in warranty on a given date, you should be able to create a calculated measure at query time using the MDX FILTER() function.

Comment: Thanks. Googling led me to that as a possibility, but I'm not really sure how to implement a filter function as I'm so new to all of this. Any pointers about how to query at a given month&year between the row's start and and dates?